# Can i serve complete Angular website to CDN (Cloudfront AWS)?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have a front-end application build in Angular 8 (website.com) and its back-end in Laravel is placed separately (api.website.com). Currently i am serving complete frontend application on CDN (cloudfront -AWS). Is the the right way to serve complete website on cdn or just the assets? Currently the website is under development.

Comment: How do you define a "complete website" (vs. assets)? An Angular application is essentially a collection of static assets (JS, CSS, images).

Comment: Complete website means the complete SSR build.

Comment: is it possible to do server side rendering through s3?

Comment: @ZainabTariq did you solved the issue and could you give an explanation. I'm looking for the same right now... Thx